# Освободи меня от цепей

Tags: стилистика

В романе Диккенса встретилось выражение:"Release me, then from the chain by which I am bound." Перевела, как "Освободи меня от цепей, которыми я связана".
Так вот, возник вопрос, является ли выражение "освободи меня от цепей" метафорой или здесь какой-то другой стилистический прием?

Answer (score 4):

Метафора, конечно.  Героиня говорит о семейных узах.  Только почему в переводе - множественное число?

> Тогда освободите меня от цепи, которой я связана.

Answer (score 3):

Метафорой данное выражение может быть только в том случае, если само выражение употреблено образно, в переносном значении. В противном случае, говорить о каком-то приеме здесь вряд ли уместно.